# calling str on a dictionary of objects

Tags: python, string, oop, repr

I have a dictionary of objects like so
`{'name1':oject_instance_1,'name2':oject_instance_2,'name3':oject_instance_3}`
In my class definition of object, I have defined both the `__str__() method` and the `__repr__()` method as follows:

```
def __str__(self):
    return('{0} pathway containing {1} genes, with a total sequence length of {2}'.format(self.id, len(self.genes), self.length))

def __repr(self):
    return self.__str__
```

In case it's important self.id is a string, self.genes is a list, and self.length is an int

The problem is when I go to print this dictionary I get:

```
{'pid1003': <Pathway.Pathway instance at 0x10169d680>, 'pid1002': <Pathway.Pathway instance at 0x10169d638>, 'pid1001': <Pathway.Pathway instance at 0x10169d5f0>}
```

but printing in a loop like

```
for v in dict.values():
    print(v)
```

works fine.

Any ideas why?
Thanks!

Comment: Is your representation method really called `__repr` (no second set of underscores)?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the code in `__repr__` be `return self.__str__()` ?  As it is, returning a method object seems a little weird...

Comment: Well that's embarassing. Thanks! :(

Comment: @mgilson, that's right. But as a side note, better `str(self)` than `self.__str__()`, if only because it's easier to type.

Comment: @senderle -- I mostly agree with that.  I was just doing it the same way the OP did it.  As a side note, couldn't you just do: `__repr__ = __str__` without needing to wrap `__str__` in another function call?  (That's most efficient and saves the most typing)

Comment: You'd more likely just implement only `__repr__`, since if you don't implement `__str__` you get the repr. But this is a bit of an odd thing to return in `__str__`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you should implement `__repr__`, not `__repr`.

**Edit:**

And `__repr__` should return a String, not a function. So, as noted in the comments, return `str(self)`.